# Some of the keys on my keyboard are broken. LXDE/Openbox. Is it possible to make openbox shortcuts that output the corresponding key globally?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, lxde, openbox

Some of the keys on my keyboard are broken. I am using LXDE/Openbox. Is it possible to make openbox shortcuts that output the corresponding key globally?

Hello,

The numbers five and six are not working on my keyboard.

I am using LXDE/Openbox.

Is it possible to make a shortcut for example Alt plus F which always output the number five globally no matter what application I am using, even if it's the browser or something else?

Vesa

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar on my machine. I have a chromebook that has a backspace key, but not a delete key. Using LXDE's keybindings, I mapped alt-backspace to delete. This requires [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdotool.1.html).

Take a look at ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml. Search for "keybind" and get to understand the syntax. Here's a chunk of my lxde-rc.xml for my mapping:

```
<keybind key="A-BackSpace">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <name>Delete</name>
    </startupnotify>
    <command>xdotool key --clearmodifiers Delete</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

That keybinding works anywhere in the LXDE session.